# Im4Java - How to make transparent PNG based watermark in corner sized proportionally

Tags: im4java

I'm trying to create transparent sized proportionally watermark. I've written something like that for beginning. How to make watermark resized proportionally and position it with margins?

```
            IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
            op.dissolve(30);
            op.gravity("SouthWest");
            op.addImage(watermarks.get("watermark"));
            op.addImage(sourceFilePath);
            op.addImage(destFilePath);
            CompositeCmd composite = new CompositeCmd();
            composite.run(op);
```

After that I want to resize whole picture. It can be done with one command?

Answer (score 0):

After two hours of playing I've got it:

```
            op.addImage(sourceFilePath);
            op.thumbnail(f.getWidth(), f.getHeight());
            op.gravity("SouthEast");
            op.draw("image Over     50,50 300,300 '"+watermarks.get(site.getPrefix())+"'");
            op.addImage(destFilePath);
            cmd.run(op);
```

Where 50,50 it's postiion of watermark, and 300,300 is size of watermark. Ufff